# Convert Object to String iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, string, object

I have got something strange:
This Code does NOT Work:
cell.imvstatus.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[tutorials objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"] ];

This code works:

cell.imvstatus.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ROR.png" ];

And in the object there is the value "ROR.png"

Whats the problem at the above one?

How can I find out a solution?
Do i have to cast it to a string ?

Comment: Go back and accept some answers to your old questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found it out:

image = "ROR.png\n"; contains a \n

I have to replace it.BUT:

OK now The Output is:
2009-11-09 09:17:31.606 remotegui[1667:207] image: ROR.png
But when i write out the length of the string the string is 8 chars long:

2009-11-09 09:17:31.606 remotegui[1667:207] bildlength: 8

Comment: you can remove '\n'  using this code
  `NSString *string=@"firstname\nlastname";
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it as a string like this:

`NScell.imvstatus.image = [UIImage imageNamed: (NSString *) [[tutorials objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"] ];`

The key is the **`(NSString *)`**.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we can assume is `[[tutorials objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]` doesn't contain ROR.png.

Try doing NSLog debugging by adding the following lines of code (and looking at the console output, in Xcode under the menu Run > Console):

```
NSLog(@"tutorials: %@", tutorials);
NSLog(@"row index: %d", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"row content: %@", [tutorials objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
NSLog(@"image: %@",
   [[tutorials objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]);
```

There probably is something unexpected there.